# Python list sorter

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that sorts a list in ascending or descending order depending on user input, however with this code I am getting an error.

```
type = input("Would you like to sort in descending or ascending order (D/A) ?")
stop = False
newlist = []

while not stop:
    value = input("""
    To add a number to the list, enter the number.
    To stop the entry process, enter 'stop'
    """)

    if value.lower() == 'stop':
        stop = True
    else:
        newlist.append(int(value))
        stop = False

if type.upper() == "A":
    newlist = newlist.sort()
elif type.upper() == "D":
    newlist = newlist.sort()
    newlist = newlist.reverse()
print(newlist)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Dev/Python/projects/orderlist.py", line 9, in <module>
    """)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Should `newlist = list.sort()` be `newlist = newlist.sort()`?

Comment: Should just be `newlist.sort()` and `newlist.reverse()`. These methods operate in-place so they don't return anything.

Comment: btw you also want to have: `if input.lower() == 'stop':` otherwise you won't be able to exit. ( **Edited to remove str()** )

Comment: Yup you're right that fixed the error but now it refuses to loop and just gives me "none" in the console :/

Comment: Should be `input.lower() == 'stop'` without the `str`, and you also shouldn't assign a new value to `input` where you want to call the built-in function `input` on the next iteration.

Comment: How do you expect something to be `"A"` or `"D"`? Should the user input another value?

Comment: You need to use something like `value = input(""" ... ` and use `value` in the next few lines of your program. (As you have it now your are redefining `input` to be a string. That means it is no longer the `input()` function)

Comment: Yes, I edited in the previous line I accidentally missed out.

Comment: @quamrana this fixed the first while loop however, afterwards, it is giving me no output in the "sorting" block of code. Thanks for your help so far though!!!

Comment: Stackoverflow does not normally allow this "Help me develop my program" approach, but somehow we are allowing it here.

Comment: Anyway, where does the value of `type` come from?

Comment: Sorry about that, I was not aware due to my recent joining of the platform and apologise for the way I am tackling this problem. Please feel free to leave this thread as I recognise I am not following the stackiquette.

Comment: @quamrana it is from the first line asking the user which sort they would like.

Comment: That code doesn't produce that error. You need to make a [mre].

Comment: Looking at the edit history, you've edited the code substantially, which is a big no-no. It sort of invalidates your question. I think [ask] covers this. Relatedly, the question doesn't have a descriptive title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the program you are looking for:

```
sortType = input("Would you like to sort in descending or ascending order (D/A) ?")

newlist = []

while True:
    value = input("""
    To add a number to the list, enter the number.
    To stop the entry process, enter 'stop'
    """)

    if value.lower() == 'stop':
        break
    newlist.append(int(value))


newlist.sort()
if sortType.upper() == "D":
    newlist.reverse()
print(newlist)
```

The first `input()` assigns to the variable named `sortType`, because `type` is currently reserved by python.

The `while` loop can be `while True:` since it will be known exactly when to exit the loop, which I do with a `break`.

Since the `break` immediately exits the loop, there is no need for an `else:`

Since the list has to be sorted, I just go ahead and sort it.

Then I check the `A / D` option and if a descending sort is required, then I `reverse()` the list.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly and I really appreciate you showing me the ropes!

Comment: You're welcome. Check my comments on how the program works. For future reference you should isolate a single fault with your program and reduce the code to reliably produce just that fault. Then you can post the code, any relevant input and actual and expected output and any Tracebacks in full.

Comment: Got it, will follow this for sure in future.